# "for becoming" versus "to become"

Tags: infinitives, ing

According to https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/support-files/purpose.pdf for+verb-ing should be used for function, to+infinitive for intention. Consider:

> ...is an essential skill required *to become / for becoming* a professional psychologist.

Is there a difference? "skill required to become" has 378k results on Google, "skill required for becoming" has 5k.

Should *required* be omitted for better style?

Another example:

> Cambridge Analytica used the five-factor model *to profile/for profiling* Facebook users.

Is there any difference?

Comment: "An essential skill for becoming" is fine, "An essential skill to become" is not.

Comment: Yes, essential and required do the same job. I'd fire one.